# Is there any way to change characters in GTA IV?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I remember in GTA: Vice City you could change characters with cheat codes. Do any such cheat codes exist for GTA IV?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can buy clothes but you cannot change the character in GTA IV.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with [Mods](http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=gta%20iv%20mods)